# Transform ssf to shp

Tags: shapefile, ssf

Do you know a free program that transform *.ssf to *.shp files?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Trimble Pathfinder Office or FME with Trimble FME extension. Both are commercial programs.

Comment: Are you implying that these are "free," as requested in the question?